# fix head while scrolling horizontal as well as vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix my head part constant when scrolling *vertical*, and should be able to scroll *horizontal* also.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="c1">
    <div id="c2">
        <ul style="font-weight:bold;position:fixed;">
            <li>Lorem ipsum wide</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>last</li><li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum wide</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>last</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum wide</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>last</li><li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum wide</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>last</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
        </ul><ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum wide</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>last</li><li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum wide</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
             <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
            <li>last</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum even more width</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li {float: left;width:200px;}
ul{clear:both;}
#c1 { overflow: scroll;height:100px; }
```

**Jquery:**

```
var sum = 0;
$("#c2 ul li").each(function(){sum += $(this).width()});
$("#c2").css('width', sum/$("#c2 ul").length);
$(function () {
  var $blue = $("#c2"),
      $pg = $("#c1"),
      $document = $(document),
      left = 0,
      scrollTimer = 0;


  // Detect horizontal scroll start and stop.
  $document.on("scroll", function () {
    var docLeft = $document.scrollLeft();
    if(left !== docLeft) {
      var self = this, args = arguments;
      if(!scrollTimer) {
        // We've not yet (re)started the timer: It's the beginning of scrolling.
        startHScroll.apply(self, args);
      }
      window.clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
      scrollTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        scrollTimer = 0;
        // Our timer was never stopped: We've finished scrolling.
        stopHScroll.apply(self, args);
      });
      left = docLeft;
    }
  });

  // Horizontal scroll started - Make div's absolutely positioned.
  function startHScroll () {
    //console.log("Scroll Start");
    $("#c3")
    // Clear out any left-positioning set by stopHScroll.
    .css("left","")
    .each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
          pos = $this.offset();
      // Preserve our current vertical position...
      $this.css("top", pos.top)
    })
    // ...before making it absolutely positioned.
    .css("position", "absolute");
  }

  // Horizontal scroll stopped - Make div's float again.
  function stopHScroll () {
    var leftScroll = $(window).scrollLeft();
   // console.log("Scroll Stop");
    $("#c3")
    // Clear out any top-positioning set by startHScroll.
    .css("top","")
    .each(function () {
      var $this = $(this), 
        pos = $this.position();
      // Preserve our current horizontal position, munus the scroll position...
      $this.css("left", pos.left-leftScroll);
      //alert(pos.left-leftScroll);
    })
    // ...before making it fixed positioned.
    .css("position", "fixed");
  }
});
```

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gAGKh/163/).
 Could any one please help me out where exactly I am going wrong.

Comment: you want to scroll on mousewheel?

Comment: Seeking something like this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/gAGKh/165) ?

Comment: You're trying to what?

Comment: @Gurami Dagundaridze it could be any way mouse wheel or arrow.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay not exactly header should scroll  horizontally as well

Comment: Did you notice that? `$document` is wrong, the good is `$(document)`. Yes, you are declarating before, but console throws `$document.on is not a function`

Comment: $document = $(document) is defined intially @Marcos Pérez Gude

Comment: See the console. Almost in the fiddle the error throws everytime.

Comment: Sometimes console save your life. I remove the initial declaration and it works now. I don't lie: http://jsfiddle.net/gAGKh/168/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want some sort of self-made table with a fixed header. You can do this by:

1. Putting the header and body in different divs.
2. Make both scrollable by adding `overflow: hidden` and `overflow:auto` to the header and body respectively.
3. Use this piece of JQuery to make them scroll horizontally simultaneously.

   ```
   $("div").scroll(function(){
       $("div:not(this)").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
   });
   ```

The spacing in both "tables" have to be the same for them to allign properly. If you have any problems: make sure the `position` of both the header and the body are either `fixed` or `absolute`.

---

**EDIT**: Changed code from `.on("scroll", function(...))` to `.scroll(function(...))`

[According to this page](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/), the first is just a shortcut for the second. But this function seems to work and the other does not.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAGKh/172/)**

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gAGKh/171/ i am not sure where exactly ia m doing mistake.check out this as well http://jsfiddle.net/gAGKh/170/

Comment: I've tried it out and added a JSFiddle of the working code. The `.on("scroll", function(..))` didn't seem to work properly so I changed it to ... well the same function. The scroll function has to be linked to `.main`, since that's the window you're actually scrolling in. Updated the post accordingly.